# WebDriver Explorer Scroll with Dynamic Elements

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

we have explorer menu (GWT + ExtJS based). and the tree nodes in the menu are dynamically displayed based on screen resolution. so here is rough visualization

- Root

  - Parent

    - Child

      - Leaf1
      - Leaf2
      - Leaf3
      - .
      - .
      - Leaf10

now when page loads initially, explorer menu shows only nodes upto Leaf3 (ie in DOM only Root,Parent,Child,Leaf1,Leaf2,Leaf3 nodes are present). Now when i scroll down Leaf4,Leaf5..Leaf10 becomes visible and Root, Parent,Child becomes invisible (not available in DOM)..again if i srcoll up Root, Parent,Child becomes visible and leaf4,leaf5,leaf10 are invisible.

The DIV element that surrounds the tree panel is the one with the “overflow:auto” style

```
<div unselectable="on" class="x-tree3-node-ct x-tree3 x-component x-unselectable" role="group" tabindex="0" hidefocus="true" id="x-auto-2" aria-activedescendant="x-auto-2__x-auto-2_x-auto-110" style="display: block; overflow: auto; width: 248px; height: 386px;"><div unselectable="on" id="x-auto-2_x-auto-3" class="x-tree3-node" role="presentation">
```

I have multiple use cases where i have to scroll up and down to reach root node and leaf nodes. so i am trying to figure out best approach to automate this.

I am using WebDriver 2.35 (java)

I tried following code, but its not very efficient if I want to scroll frequently up and down

```
public void scrollToTreeElement(String treeNodeText){
    String nodeElement = HTMLElement.ADMIN_TREE_NODE+"[contains(text(),'"+treeNodeText+"')]";
    WebElement treeNode = null;

    try{                        
         treeNode = driver.findElement(By.xpath(nodeElement));
         treeNode.click();
        logger.info(treeNode.getText());
    }catch(NoSuchElementException e){
        logger.info("inside catch");

        String allElements = "//*[@class='x-tree3-node']";
        List<WebElement> allSNMPElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath(allElements));
        for(WebElement element : allSNMPElements){
// here i am filtering allElements that doesnt have 'span' node (that has tree text) and then scroll to this element
            if(element.findElements(By.tagName("span")).size()==0){
                scrollToViewPort(element);

            }
        }
        List<WebElement> allTreeNodes = driver.findElements(By.className("x-tree3-node-text"));

    }       
}   

public void scrollToViewPort(WebElement element){       
    ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);",element);               
}
```

any pointers..?

Comment: Just the most obvious speedup (or at least I hope it's a speedup) - when looking for `allSNMPElements`, don't search by XPath, use `By.className("x-tree3-node")`. Or directly use `By.xpath("//*[@class='x-tree3-node' and not(.//span)]")` to filter the elements that don't have a `span` node as a descendant right away (no filtering needed). And you don't do anything with `allTreeNodes`, but I feel that's a result of code shortening to make it fit the question, right?

Comment: thanks for your comment, yep i get your point, initially i had xapth expression to try out so i used By.xpath...but it doesnt solve my scroll issue :(